# Open a Sqlite db in a webview

Tags: android, html, sqlite, webview

I'm having some problems with android webview, SQLite and my target device. On a physical device, the database is not accessible(see errors at the end).

The setup of the webview:

```
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    settings.setDatabasePath("/data/data/de.sqlite.webview/databases");
```

I'm defining the webview in the `onCreate` method, and setting the update quota twice as high as estimated or bigger than in the HTML5 definition.

```
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    @Override
    public void onExceededDatabaseQuota(String url, String databaseIdentifier, long currentQuota, long estimatedSize, long totalUsedQuota, WebStorage.QuotaUpdater quotaUpdater)
    {
            quotaUpdater.updateQuota(204801); //estimatedSize * 2
    }
}); 


    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {                 
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading( ... ) 
    }
```

On the Emulator and on Chrome everything works fine, but if I deploy the app to my galaxys2 I'm getting an error: ***openDatabase is not defined***.

The following html-code works in chrome and in the emulated webview:

```
    db = new HKSQL();
    db.openSQL();
    today = getTodayDate();
    createDbTable_LastLogin();

    //HKSQL Class 
    function HkSQL(){
    this.query;
    this.result;
    this.database;
    }

    HkSQL.prototype.openSQL = function(){
    this.database = openDatabase("hkapp","1.0","HKApp","65536");    
    } 

    //an example query to create my db
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS HK_lastlogin (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, datum TEXT NOT NULL)
```

I have no clue why it doesn't work on my device. I thought about read and write permissions, but the `.db` file is already created. 
Here are some error messages which, I think, target to the same problem:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: openDatabase is not defined 
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'openDatabase'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was that **both** Webviews need to initialized as WebChromeClients with full features.

```
myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.l_webview);

myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {  });
myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() { ... } );


myWebView2 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.l_navi);

myWebView2.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {        });
myWebView2.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() { ... } );
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't that be `dbclassname.openDatabase` instead of `window.openDatabase`?

**EDIT**

There is an SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2474524/1105376) and the only difference I see between what they have and what you have is this line:

```
settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
```

Try adding that and see if it works then.

**Edit 2**

You have not set an orientation fro your LinearLayout so it is defaulting to horizontal, where you have both webviews using layout_width="match_parent", which would push the second one right off the screen.

You should add `android:orientation="vertical"` to the linearlayout xml, and change l_webview to `android:layout_height="0dp"  android:layout_weight="1"`.  That will make the l_webview take up all remaining space after the other one is in place.

I don't know if that will fix your issue, but it will make both views visible without pushing one off the screen.

You also need to use findViewById to get the id of each separate view.

Comment: you are right, cutted of too much code. I added the description of the class. 
Its realy strange, when the AVD emulates 2.3.3 everything works but on 4.0.3 there is the same error as on my sgs2(4.0.4)

Comment: Here is the Same Problem http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/issues/detail?id=425

Comment: Followed some links from there around.  I only see one difference from what you have.  They added `settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);`.

Comment: @Edit2
The layout was okay, thanks for the tip, but it doesnt solve the problem with the two webviews. With only one it works